# How to paste texts into columns side by side with word

Tags: ms-word

I have some problem with the Microsoft word.

I inserted a table with 2 column and then pasted on the 1st column ,a numerous amount of text.But now it happened that I've had a 1000+ page bt the texts are only in the 1st columns of the all page.the right columns are totally blank.
like I have.....

12 --

34 --

56 --

bt i need

12 56

34 78

So I need to paste the texts and the texts have to be arranged in the columns serially by horizontal order.and after filling up the columns in a page the text will be continued on the next page.
Its impossible to paste the texts individually.It will take maybe 500 hours.
please help me

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  This site helps people exchange questions and answers about programming.  If you've written some software to help you solve this problem, we'd be very happy to help you expand or fix it.  Show us your code, and we'll go from there.

Comment: what are you using for you word programming, office interop or OpenXML ?? more info about your setup and any code if possible..?

Answer (score 0):

Worst case scenario write a javascript that will correct the content of a text area.

I can help you write one if this solution will help you.

Basically, create an HTML page locally with a text-area and button.  Paste in the text area and call javascript on the click to take the content, fix it, then put it back.

Comment: Thanks.Bt i cant do that.i'm really sorry.I need a easier solution